# C# <LIST> How to check for non-unique values in the list?

Tags: c#, list, collections, iteration

This is the constructor (it's fullpropped, but here I only show 1st line):

```
Public Class Player (string firstName, string lastName, string email)
```

Program:

```
Player player1 = new Player("Mike","Dalton", md@mail.com);
Player player2 = new Player("Mario","Davis", mdavis@mail.com);
Player player3 = new Player("Mia","Duncan", md@mail.com);
...

List<Player> players = new List<Player> { player1, player2, player3};
```

There are 3 players in the list.  The real list is pretty long.  There needs  to be a check if all email-adresses are unique.
(As you see: email_player1 = email_player 3)

At the end, a simple message (console.writeline) should tell whether or not there are email_doubles or not.

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select(...)` will help you get the attribute of the elements in the list.

`Distinct()` will help you make the list contains unique elements from the list.

If you want to check all elements are unique, you could use:

```
bool isUnique = players.Select(x => x.Email).Distinct().Count() == players.Select(x => x.Email).Count();
```

With:

- `players.Distinct().Count()`: count the unique elements.
- `players.Count()`: count the list elements.
- If they are same (`isUnique = true`), then the all the elements in list are unique.

Comment: I ended up integrating your suggestion.  1 line, very simple to understand & 100% effective

Answer (score 3):

try this...
this will give you list of all the duplicate Emails that exists in the list.

```
 players.GroupBy(x => x.Email).SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1));
```

Comment: The `ToList()` seems unneccesary

Comment: yes, actually I tried it on my machine and copy and pasting added that. Thanks for reminding

Comment: Hi , i tried the (edited) version, but since my knowledge of LINQ is pretty poor atm, i couldn't build further on it.  But thanks for the advice, I can see what you are going for.

Comment: OK, I (finally) caught up with LINQ, and figured out how to implement your solution ...
Great answer @KovidPurohit !

`var listDoubleEmail = players.GroupBy(x => x.Email).SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1));
            foreach (var double in listDoubleEmail )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(double .Email);
            }`

Comment: Yes, this is the way you implement.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following approach:

```
List<string> emailList = players.Select(x => x.Email).ToList();
if (emailList.Count > emailList.Distinct().Count())
{
   Console.WriteLine("Duplicate email address found.");
}
```

If you want to display duplicate email addresses specifically then can also try the following approach:

```
var playersGroupByEmailList = players.GroupBy(x => x.Email).Select(g => new { Email = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
playersGroupByEmailList = playersGroupByEmailList.Where(x => x.Count > 1).ToList();
if (playersGroupByEmailList.Any())
{
   foreach (var playerGroupByEmail in playersGroupByEmailList)
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"{playerGroupByEmail.Email} is duplicate.");
   }
}
```

Comment: `var distinctPlayersCount = players.Select(player=>player.Email).Distinct().Count()`  would be better as it iterates once over the list when `.Count()` is executed

Comment: @Ramesh thanx for your suggestion. I have edited my answer

Comment: Excellent, this is just what i was looking for.  It's just a bit too advanced for me at the moment to start applying, since I haven't got a full understanding of LINQ yet.
So I guess: within a month or so i'll start applying your solution.
Seems 100% legit

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the email address to be like a key of a database table in that it is unique and only want to store one of each key/e-mail then maybe List is not the best collection.

You can instead use `HashSet` which only accepts unique items.

See Microsoft documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0

You declar it like this

```
HashSet<Player> players = new HashSet<Player>();
```

When you try to add it, then it returns true to false depending if it was accepted (is unique) or not.

Add to set:

```
if(players.Add(player))
    Console.Writeline($"Player {player} was added OK");
else
    Console.Writeline($"Player with email {player.Email} already exists in the collection!");
```

In order to check for uniqueness then you need to implement in `IEquatable<T>` your class

```
public class Player:  IEquatable<Player>
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    //Other properties, Constructor & methods etc.
   
    //It is important to implement GetHashCode!
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Email.GetHashCode();   
    }
 
    public bool Equals(Player other)
    {
        return this.Email.Equals(other.Email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very handy info for future app.  Thx Jason!

Answer (score 1):

As a basic way, you can do like below:

```cs
List<string> controlList = new List<string>();
foreach (var player in PlayersInfo)
{
    if (controlList.Contains(player.Email))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("there is a duplicate with" + player.email);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(player.Email)
    }
    controlList.Add(player.Email);
}
```

Comment: A `HashSet<string>` instead of a `List<string>` would make this code shorter and much faster.

Comment: @TdW  Rica Ederim, you're wellcome